# several size with shrine don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-uploading, shrine

I use the gem Shrine for uploding image on my web site.
I want to have several size for my image (to create a photo album with miniature)

So i write in my upload file like in the shrine's readme :

```
require "image_processing/mini_magick"

class ImageUploader < Shrine
  include ImageProcessing::MiniMagick

  plugin :processing
  plugin :delete_raw
  plugin :determine_mime_type
  plugin :logging, logger: Rails.logger
  plugin :remove_attachment
  plugin :store_dimensions
  plugin :validation_helpers
  plugin :versions

  Attacher.validate do
    validate_max_size 5.megabytes, message: 'is too large (max is 5 MB)'
    validate_mime_type_inclusion ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
  end

  process(:store) do |io, context|
    original = io.download
    pipeline = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)

    size_800 = pipeline.resize_to_limit!(800, 800)
    size_500 = pipeline.resize_to_limit!(500, 500)
    size_300 = pipeline.resize_to_limit!(300, 300)

  original.close!

  { original: io, large: size_800, medium: size_500, small: size_300 }
  end
end
```

But the assets :original :large :medium and :small have got the same sizes...

I maybe make a mistake in my uploadfile... Could you see it ?

Comment: Does your image by any change have dimensions smaller than 300x300? `#resize_to_limit` will downsize the image if it's larger than specified dimensions, but it won't upsize images that are smaller.

Comment: You have a good brain and i have a bad one... The code don't work any more but that is one of the problem